# Drop Down menu to be in front if jquery dialog opened

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made a drop down menu which is working fine, but when i open a jquery dialog window, and then when i go for a drop down menu its menu is keep hiding behind the jquery dialog window, although i want the menu opened to be at front.

this is jquery code.
    (document).ready(function() {

```
    $('#nav li').hover(function() {
        //show its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideDown(200);

    }, function() {
        //hide its submenu
        $('ul', this).slideUp(100);
    });

    $('ul li').click(function() {
        $('ul',this).slideUp(100);
    });
});
```

I have tried z-index but it doesn't work either. Below is the css.

```
#nav {
margin: 0 0 0 5px;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
float: left;
display: block;
position: relative;
background: #025b87;
z-index: 500;
}

#nav li a {
display: block;
padding: 8px 5px 0 5px; 
height: 23px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-align: left;
color: #FFFFFF;
}
#nav li a:hover {   
background-color: #d1d3d4;
color: #000000;
border-width:1px;
}
#nav li ul li a:hover { 
background-color: #d1d3d4;
color: #000000; 
}
```

Comment: could you put up an example in jsfiddle for us to better understand the problem?

Comment: Something I discovered recently is that floated elements do not seem to respect z-index. I'm not sure why or if that is always the case. Nonetheless, if you can avoid the float, that might fix your problem. You might also trying applying z-index to #nav directly since it is not floated.

Comment: I have figured it out, the default zIndex of dialog is 1000 and i was giving 500 zindex to nav menu. so it means the higher the zindex is, the more priority of an element is to be. so i must give the value higher than the deafult zindex value of dialog. so i have given the #nav li zindex to 1500 or any value greater than 1000. now 1500>1000. so the priority of #nav li in the stack is now greater than the jquery dialog. I will put this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out, the default zIndex of dialog is 1000 and i was giving 500 zindex to nav menu. so it means the higher the zindex is, the more priority of an element is to be. so i must give the value higher than the deafult zindex value of dialog. so i have given the #nav li zindex to 1500 or any value greater than 1000. now 1500>1000. so the priority of #nav li in the stack is now greater than the jquery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I think jQuery dialog applies some css rules, always to be in front of all other elements. Have a look at this, it will probably give you your answer. ;)

Comment: where to look jeremy, any link.

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=jquery+dialog ...